# How to insert own data by using OpenSearch dashboard in opensearch

Tags: elastic-stack, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, amazon-opensearch

I am very new to opensearch. In kibana we have option called Upload a file by which we can upload our own data set, I just switched to opensearch and trying to add data using opensearch dashboard to querying it in opensearch.

Please let me know how to do the same.

Thanks.

Comment: You can add Data to opensearch with curl and JSON. There are existing solutions for many programming languages, but I have not seen a solution with the Dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

In the OpenSearch dashboard, you can go to dev tools to make curl commands against your cluster, and index documents via PUT requests.

https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/document-apis/index-document/